# Rewrite post slug redirect don't work for a custom post status

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, slug

I have a custom post type with rewrite rule:

```
$args = array( 'labels'         => $labels,
    'public'        => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_ui'       => true,
    'show_in_menu'  => false,
    'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'homework-tasks'),
    'hierarchical'  => TRUE,
    'capabilities'  => array( 'edit_post'=>'edit_emails',
    'read_post'=>'edit_emails', 'delete_post'=>'delete_emails' ),
    'supports'      => array( 'title','editor','revisions', 'comments' ),
);
register_post_type ( 'homework', $args);
```

And custom post status:

```
            register_post_status( 'for_checking', [
                'public' => true
            ]);
```

The problem is, that posts with a new status (for_checking) are not redirected like:

```
mysite.com/homework/post-name
->
mysite.com/homework-tasks/post-name
```